# Creating a mask on UIView corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have build a simple switch button :

[image]

And on tap of "A" of "C" the red middle part is animated to the left or to the right.

But as you can see, my rounded corners background is still white. how to i get is to have a mask on the view that is will be clear?

This is the code i'm using:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CategortSwitch" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

        //Im making the backround color clear so this should not happen..

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setup
{
    self.backRoundView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:223.0/255.0 green:94.0/255.0 blue:95.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    self.backRoundView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.backRoundView .layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    //And the mask is set to YES:

    self.backRoundView .layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.backRoundView .layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
}
```

Also, when I animate the red view to the left or the right, the corners do not get the radius of the `UIView` it is in, the corners stay pointed with the slides to the left or the right.

Comment: You can use segment controller

Comment: Yup it is a better option, thanks! but it will still be much appreciated if someone could explain how to do the masking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you posted is an object derived from `UIView`, I'm guessing the white corners are from the `UIView` background color.  Set the border on self.layer and not self.backRoundView.layer.

You could also set self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; but then you'll need to set self.backRoundView.backgroundColor to [UIColor whiteColor].